# Fleet Api diferent from Route API - Invalid POI

Tags: api, gps

Something isn't correct with HERE API:

- This  **is working** if I use https://route.api.here.com

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_code=**APP_CODE**&app_id=**APP_ID**&waypoint0=geo!40.881402,-8.633051&waypoint1=geo!38.6143899,-1.1041018&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:enabled&language=pt-pt&routeAttributes=shape
```

- This **isn't working** if I use http://fleet.api.here.com

```
http://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_code=**APP_CODE**&app_id=**APP_ID**&waypoint0=40.881402,-8.633051&waypoint1=38.6143899,-1.1041018&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:enabled&language=pt-pt
```

I received this error:

```
{
    "issues": [
        {
            "message": "Cannot match 38.6143899/-1.1041018 onto a road link with 100.0m search radius"
        },
        {
            "message": "Request id: 5c3aee72-e8f5-4c34-b96c-7c3e3cce5c02"
        }
    ],
    "response": null,
    "error_id": "5c3aee72-e8f5-4c34-b96c-7c3e3cce5c02",
    "response_code": "400 Bad Request"
}
```

But using the link https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/cost_optimized_route, I saw this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I research the API and if i increase the mapMatchRadius option to 500 m is working. It's very strange. The road exists in Here Maps. Someone from the Here Support Team can provide an input?